# Как добавить/удалить запись в базу данных, чтобы таблица обновлялась автоматически и не приходилось перезапускать приложение? С++/qt

Tags: c++, qt

[image: первый скрин, символ - "*"]

[image: второй скрин, символ - "!"]

Я добавил на форму QTableView и подключил базу(sqlite). Есть два слота на кнопку, при нажатии на которые добавляются/удаляются строки.
При добавлении строки слева появляется "*". При удалении появляется "!". Нужно, чтобы не было этих символов. При добавлении шла следующая
цифра строки, а не символ "*". При удалении строка удалялась целиком, а не оставляла за собой "!" и не приходилось перезапускать приложение. Как такое можно сделать?

Remove/Add Methods:

```
void MainWindow::on_action_AddRow_triggered()
{
    model->insertRow(model->rowCount());
}
void MainWindow::on_actionDelRow_triggered()
{
    model->removeRow(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать кнопку, которая будет выводить данные таблицы через SQL-запрос. Например, есть кнопка "Показать таблицу студентов" и sql-запрос через SELECT. Еще есть и ваши кнопки с изменением/удалением/добавлением данных, внутри которых вы можете вызвать искусственное нажатие кнопки "Показать таблицу студентов"

Либо можете создать не кнопку, а отдельный метод который будет запрашивать из БД данные таблицы и выводить их вам

Comment: Он сделал это в конструкторе model = new QSqlTableModel(this, db);
    model->setTable("students");
    model->select();

Comment: Я частично добился результата, добавив в слот on_action_AddRow_triggered() эти строки: query->exec("INSERT INTO students(ФИО) VALUES('');");
    model->select(); Но когда я начинаю удалять записи, то все сбрасывается в исходное состояние

Comment: Вообщем, я сам решил свой вопрос, но вам в любом случае спасибо))